# mongodb sum aggregation return float instead of integer

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document which `history` embedded field is as below:

```
first_pn_data = {'_cls': 'InstallationEmbeddedHistory',
 'coverage': 0.8197712971965834,
 'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 0, 0),
 'estimated_installs': 39349022,
 'popularity_rank': 0,
 'rank': 1851}

second_pn_data = {'_cls': 'InstallationEmbeddedHistory',
 'coverage': 0.8197712971965834,
 'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 0, 0),
  'estimated_installs': 23412618,
 'popularity_rank': 0,}
```

The `estimated_installs` field is an integer.
when I run the following query:

```
query = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "package_name": {
                "$in": ["first_pn", "second_pn"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$history"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$history.date",
            "total": {
                "$sum": "$history.estimated_installs"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

the result for the above date is:

```
{'_id': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 0, 0), 'total': 62761640.54968266}
```

while I expect the `total=62761640`.

I don't know why the result is float and has a decimal.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: do you want to get the result as `int` or do you want to know why it's not returning `int`?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why it's float. This is my fault or something else?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. can you share the exact document are you using

Comment: sorry I edit the second_pn_data so `first_pn_data['estimated_installs']=39349022` and `second_pn_data['estimated_installs'] =23412618` so sum of them is `62761640` but the query return `62761640.5496826`

Comment: post the complete document to test your query